# Unable to start uwAmpp Mysql server

Tags: mysql, wamp, uwamp

I have Xampp in my computer and all thing works well; but when I uninstall it and install uwAmp instead, I can not start MySQL server.(uwApm is a portable version of wamp).
I have search the web for my problem and found out that I must delete any my.ini file in other places in my computer except for uWamp folder; But I have not any my.ini file in my computer except for uwAmp.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the MySQL error log, and also Windows Event Viewer. Mysql reports error to the Windows logging system if they happen before it can open its error log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the uwAmp control panel, click on XDebug client and select "Remove MySql log".Then try to start MySQL  in the top of control panel.
It must works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you use windows 10/11

look for file my_uwamp.ini (or just use the small icon in cpanel to edit mysql config file) and add this:

innodb_flush_method=normal

now it should work